# Screen flicker caused by GPU?

Tags: display, gpu, overheating

My [laptop with these specs](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/N550JK/specifications/) recently started to have issues with the screen flickering or turning black entirely.

Normally I would have said it's just the connector cable, but some of the behaviour make me think it could be something else:

- If I attach an external screen, only the laptop screen is affected.

BUT:

- Restarting the computer solves the problem (until is usually reoccurs after 5-10min)
- When I put the laptop on table which is heat conductive, the problem doesn't occur.

Is there a possibility that this problem could be caused by the GPU overheating or any other part of the mainboard? If so, why would an external monitor not be affected? Is a different chip responsible for the screen on the laptop or the external screen? Is the NVIDIA GeForce GTX850M that is part of the laptop taking care of both internal an external monitor? What part does the integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600 play?

Any suggestions how to further troubleshoot this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility that this problem could be caused by the GPU overheating or any other part of the mainboard? If so, why would an external monitor not be affected?

Agree.

It could be that built-up heat is causing something to expand just enough to disturb an internal connection.  Open up the laptop and reseat the LVDS or similar cable connecting internal display to the motherboard.

It's also possible a component called the *inverter* (in the laptop's display) is going out - it regulates power to the display.  These are not too difficult to find and replace (usually beneath the bottom part of the bezel of the screen - high voltage, do not work on while system has power), but check the cable first.

Comment: The specs: 15.6" 16:9 HD (1366x768)/IPS FHD (1920x1080) `LED Backlight` Non-Glare LCD Panel